# Is it possible to turn off application state saving in OS X Lion?

Tags: macos, osx-lion, system-preferences

In OS X Lion it saves the state of an application before you exit an app so that when you start it you can pick up where you left off.  This is a cool feature and all, but I would prefer to disable this feature.  A lot of times I have many tabs/windows open in an app and I just want to quit the app and close out of everything, but this is a big pain now in Lion.

Does anyone know how to disable this feature?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'll give you two options.  One possibility is to disable it entirely, in System Preferences -> General pane -> disable "Restore windows when quitting and re-opening apps".

You can also disable it temporarily while quitting an application.  Just quit with <kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>Option</kbd>-<kbd>Q</kbd> -- a shortcut for "Quit and Discard Widows", which is also available under the application menu *if* you hold the <kbd>Option</kbd> key.

Update: [This posting at MacFixIt](http://reviews.cnet.com/8301-13727_7-20083707-263/managing-mac-os-x-lions-application-resume-feature/) gives a third option: you can effectively disable state restoration for a particular application by emptying out its Saved Application State folder (~/Library/Saved Application State/com.something.applicationid), and then locking the folder.